# Flash File on DVF playing in fullscreen

Tags: flash, dvd

A flash movie has been created with the stage of 1200 x 800px. The work is published as a projector and burned on dvd.

However when on different screen size (bigger than 1200px), when clicking on fullscreen the images and text in the flash file become pixelated.

Is there any solutions to avoid bad quality flash work being displayed by handling the multi-screen problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
1) add the code in your flash file

stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

2) Select all your Graphic Files in the Library, Select their properties, Set Allow Smoothing to Yes and Compression: JPEG. Image Quality: 100%

This works as the images are no longer pixelated in full screen!